# (Highcharts) Display Newest Data From Text File Only

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a text file that appends new data to it hourly. I'm trying to display the last week's worth of data only, so 7 * 24 = 168 points. I would still like the text file to retain the old information so my clients can download all previous data as a csv.

I believe this can be done in Highcharts' script but cannot find any relevant information online. Help or pointing me towards the right information would be appreciated.

This is the text file: http://komtechmonitoring.com/92409w4.txt

This is my Highcharts code for integrating the text file:

```
    $.get('92409w4.txt', function(data) {
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    lines = lines.map(function(line) {var data = line.split(',');
    data[1] = parseFloat(data[1]);return data;});
    var series = {data: lines};
    options.series.push(series);
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);});});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this after setting lines...

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
lines.splice(0, lines.length-168);
```

this should remove all but last 168